# Overloading the Output Stream Operator for a Class

Tags: c++

Suppose this is my class:

```
class Student {
    std::string name;
    int CWID;
public:
    Student(std::string name = "N/A", int CWID = 99999999) : this->name(name), this->CWID(CWID) {}
};
```

Now, how do I overload the output stream operator `<<` that will print all the data in the class. I'm guessing this is equivalent to the `toString()` method in Java but kindly show me how to do it in C++.

Comment: This has been asked many times, what about the previous answers to similar questions did not help you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 1):

Add member functions to the class that return the name and CWID.

```
std::string getName() const {return name;}
int getCWID() const {return CWID;}
```

Then, add a non-member function to write the data out to a stream.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Student const& s)
{
   return out << s.getName() << " " << s.getCWID();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sahu, you're really helpful as always.

Answer (score 0):

You could write non-member function

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& stud)
{
  os << stud.name << " " << stud.CWID;
  return os;
}
```

and declare it as friend function in your class

```
class Student {
    std::string name;
    int CWID;
public:
    Student(std::string name = "N/A", int CWID = 99999999) : this->name(name), this->CWID(CWID) {}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& stud);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it:

```
class Student {
    std::string name;
    int CWID;
public:
    Student(std::string name = "N/A", int CWID = 99999999) : name(name), CWID(CWID) {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Student& student);
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Student& student)
{
    stream << '(' << student.name << ", " << student.CWID << ')';
    return stream;
}
```

Please note that this overloaded function is not part of the class.